# Alternatives to ImageNet

Tags: data-request, imagenet

I'm interested in freely available crowdsourced images with semantic tagging similar to what ImageNet provides. Are there any alternatives to [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/) here?

Update: I just found NEIL http://www.neil-kb.com/ but it doesn't seem that open. There's only one training set from 2013 available. Anybody knows if its trained models are available for download?

Answer (score 2):

I think [flickr's machine tags](https://code.flickr.net/tag/machine-tags/) fit this category. [Their hiearchies](http://code.flickr.net/2008/12/15/machine-tag-hierarchies/) sound similar to ImageNet's.

Answer (score 2):

Wikimedia Commons at https://commons.wikimedia.org is the sister site of Wikipedia, and contains over 40 million free media files, - with a high proportion being photos you can use as an alternative to ImageNet.

The media files in Wikimedia Commons are usually tagged with one or more categories from the Wikimedia Commons hierarchical category system. For instance, the category "Resting lions" is here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Resting_lions